# How to call a php class in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a nice demo importer which is working fine but with a category post count issue so there is  plugin which is fixing this and I'm trying to integrate into my demo importer library.

[This plugin here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/fix-category-count/) is fixing the issue after demo import but requires to go into the plugin page selecting post types in order to click on submit button.

Well this is the plugin admin page:

```
<?php 
    if($_POST) {
        if(!check_admin_referer('select_post_types_'.get_current_user_id() )){
            echo 'That is not allowed'; exit;
        }
        $fixes = $_POST['fix'];
        foreach($fixes AS $fix_id){
            $fix = new Fix_Category_Count();
            $fix->post_type = $fix_id;
            if($fix->process()){
                $updated = TRUE;
            }

        }
    }
?>


<div>
    <?php echo "<h2>" . __( 'Fix Category Count Settings', 'fix_category_count' ) . "</h2>"; ?>

    <h3>Select Post Types to Fix</h3>
    <form name="site_data_form" method="post" action="<?php echo str_replace( '%7E', '~', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>">
        <div class="sa_block">
            <?php
                $post_types = get_post_types(array('public'=>TRUE));
                foreach($post_types AS $post_type){
                    ?>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="post_type" name="fix[]" id="fix_<?=$post_type; ?>" value="<?=$post_type; ?>" /> <label for="fix_<?=$post_type; ?>"><?=ucwords(preg_replace("/_/"," ",$post_type)); ?> (<?=$post_type;?>)</label><br />
                    <?php
                }
            ?>
                <br><br>
                 <a href="#" class="select_boxes" rel="all" id="all">Select All</a> | 
                 <a href="#" class="select_boxes" rel="none" id="none">Deselect All</a>
                </div>
        </div>

        <?php wp_nonce_field('select_post_types_'.get_current_user_id()); ?>

        <div class="submit">
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="<?php _e('Fix Categories Now', '' ) ?>" />
        </div>      
        <?php if($updated){ ?>
            <div class="updated"><p><strong><?php _e('Categories Updated.' ); ?></strong></p></div>
        <? } ?>
    </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
if(jQuery){
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('.select_boxes').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            if($(this).attr('rel')=='all'){
                $('.post_type').each(function() {
                    this.checked = true;
                });
            }
            else{
                $('.post_type').each(function() {
                    this.checked = false;
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
</script>
```

So the CLASS of the plugin is [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/KZeni/5f7c14e4ea988e09d3daa8507daac1bf/raw/0df25738ab965d2c486089d3f72a2e50655dbff0/inc-fix_category_count_engine.php)

**I want to use only the class without the admin page with something like this:**

```
    ob_start();
    if ( 'complete' == $response['process'] ) {

        // Set imported menus to registered theme locations
        $locations = get_theme_mod( 'nav_menu_locations' ); // registered menu locations in theme

        $menus = wp_get_nav_menus(); // registered menus

        if ( $menus ) {
            foreach( $menus as $menu ) { // assign menus to theme locations
                if( 'Main Menu' == $menu->name ) {
                    $locations['primary'] = $menu->term_id;
                    break;
              }

            }
        }

        set_theme_mod( 'nav_menu_locations', $locations ); // set menus to locations
         global $wp_rewrite;
         $wp_rewrite->set_permalink_structure('/%postname%/');
         $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();

        // I want to add the plugin functionality as a last process here!

       }
    ob_end_clean();
```

I'm not a php developer yet but I would like to get this working without fixing the category count using the plugin page options but directly on the function above and with the [php class](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/KZeni/5f7c14e4ea988e09d3daa8507daac1bf/raw/0df25738ab965d2c486089d3f72a2e50655dbff0/inc-fix_category_count_engine.php) provided by plugin.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried `$class = new TheClassName();` and then just call the methods you need `$class->theMethod('some-argument')`?

Comment: I have tried this `$fixes = $_POST['fix'];
  foreach($fixes AS $fix_id){
   $fix = new Fix_Category_Count();
   $fix->post_type = $fix_id;
   if($fix->process()){
    $updated = TRUE;
   }
  
  }` but maybe I have to make an update here by adding all existing post type ids?

Comment: `$fix = new Fix_Category_Count();
                 $fix->$update_category_correct_count;` ? How to create a argument from that php class? so what Im looking for is updating all term post count which is working fine with this plugin. I want only the final process functionality into the  `if ( 'complete' == $response['process'] ) { `